# toRightDisjunction in Cats

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats

I did not find a function, similar to `toRightDisjunction` in `scalaz`, to convert `Option` to `Either`. Why does not `cats` provide such a function ?

Comment: `Option` already has `toLeft` and `toRight`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I should have noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scala library provides these functions via `Option.toLeft` and `Option.toRight`:

```
val s = "Oh no".some
val leftRes: Either[String, Int] = s.toLeft(42)
val rightRes: Either[Int, String] = s.toRight(42)
```

Since `Either[A, B]` has become the defacto standard in 2.12 (replacing `Xor`) after being right biased, there's no need for any additional extension methods.